# Show surjectivity of a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra

It pains me to say that this bewilders me, but here's the problem.

All I want to do is show that:

Given $T$ a linear operator on some finite-dimensional space $V$, with the property that $Im(T) = Im(T^2)$, show that $T: Im(T) \to Im(T)$ is surjective.

My thoughts so far:

We have some $w \in Im(T)$, then $Tw \in Im(T^2) = Im(T)$.
Here I simply want to claim that since $Tw \in Im(T)$ for an arbitrary $w$, I will hit every element in the image. Is this really enough? It doesn't sit right somehow. My thought process is that if you give me any element in $Im(T)$, and I run $T$ on that element, I will be in $Im(T^2)$, but since $Im(T) = Im(T^2)$..... and here my brain freezes. How can I garantee that I will cover $Im(T)$ entirely?

This feels like one of those things that are so easy that they become hard.

Any applicable theory is appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have it. But here is an argument just in case.

Let $T(x)\in Im(T)$. Since $Im(T)=Im(T^2)$ there exists $y\in V$ such that $T^2(y)=T(x)$. But then $T(T(y))=T(x)$, that is, $T:Im(T)\to Im(T)$ is surjective.

Comment: Sigh.... it really isn't rocket science, often it feels like I'm nuking an anthill, making simple problems more complicated than they are. Makes me feel stupid as hell...
Thanks for the explanation, I'm drawing a picture for myself right now, just to be sure that it 'feels' right. :)

Comment: @JuliusL33t: Haha! No problem.

Answer (score 1):

Let $w\in Im(T)$ then $\exists x\in V$ such that $T(x)=w$. $Im(T)=Im(T^2)$ so $w\in Im(T)=Im(T^2)$ implies that $\exists y\in V$ such that $T^2(y)=w$. Now let $T(y)$ as the element we wanted.

Comment: @amWhy: Done! ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

Take some $t\in \operatorname{Im}(T)$. Since $\operatorname{Im}(T)=\operatorname{Im}(T^2)$, there is some $v\in V$ such that $T^2v = t$. Now look at $Tv$.